# can not set up SDK

Tags: android

Please help!  Thanks in advance.

I loaded "android-sdk_r06-windows". I also install JavaSDK. When I click "SDK setup", I got:

<<https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: HTTPS SSL error. You might want to force download through HTTP in the settings.>>>

If I directly go to "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml", my web page show source code:

I am blocked.

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK setup settings you can change the url to not use https and use http which is what it is telling you to do. So in the setup click the settings button and change the url to be just http.

Answer (score 0):

JSBangs,
Sorry you're having trouble with this.  Setting up the Android development environment can sometimes be a real beast.

What I really suggest doing is something that's quite difficult for me to practice as I preach hah.  Read a nice set of instructions, and don't skip over any sections that you think you already know - there's tons of gotchas and strange issues that occur, which can be avoided for the most part by following directions to the letter.

A good friend of mine named Michael Dietz prepared an amazing write up on setting up an Android development environment.  I HIGHLY reccomend giving it a read, and I sincerely hope it helps you out!

You can find it at http://www.mobiusbay.com/home/android%E2%80%93day0gettingstarted

### Best of luck in all of your dev efforts!

Adam